# How to save the file content

Tags: c, file-io

thanks for answers but before now my code can read from the file and print out the values in the area! My question is how to use these values outside the "FOR LOOP". SINCE i dont want to keep reading the file anytime i need the values, Assuming the array data[][] contains all the contents of the file.......IS IT POSSIBLE TO CALL THE ARRAY OUTSIDE THE LOOP AND ITS PRINTS OUT ALL THE FILE CONTENTS?

```
//file
S (20,22)(129,37)
S (10,18)(40,200)
S (10,20)(39,15)
S (30,400)(750,200)
S (160,70)(240,20)
S (40,40)(10,39)
S (6,65)(94,2)
S (404,40)(110,39)
S (86,61)(50,19)

  //part of code.........

      int count=1;   

       for (i=0; i <= count; i++)
       {
         while(fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)\n", &a, &b, &c, &d) !=EOF)
         {

 data[i][0] =a;
 data[i][1] =b;
 data[i][2] =c;
 data[i][3] =d;

 printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3]);
  XDrawLine(display_ptr, win, gc_grey,a, b, c, d);

    count++;
   }

 // want to call the array data[i][j] here outside the iteration above..
  int j1=0;  
       for (i=0; i <= 19, j1<=3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",data[i][0]);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You never increment `i` in your loop. Moreover, the outer loop does nothing.

Try something like this instead:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; fscanf(...) != EOF; ++i)
{
    // if i == current array size of data, reallocate or break

    data[i][0] = a;
    data[i][1] = b;
    data[i][2] = c;
    data[i][3] = d;

    // etc.
}

// Now data[k] holds data for k in [0, i)
```

You have to think about what happens when there are more lines in your file than you have array elements. You could either reallocate (if the array is dynamic), or you could wrap the entire construction inside another loop that processes the file in chunks. You should also check whether the `fscanf` operation succeeds at extracting all the data!

Comment: tried it but it loops twice. that is it reads every thing in the file and starts again for the second time